# Is there a way to end a conversation programatically using Node.js in Dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, api-ai

Is there a way to end the conversation with code in Node.js? Following the documentation provided by google I've tried using `agent.end()` but it doesn't work (i guess it did in the first version). I don't want to use `set intent` as end of conversation option since I want the conversation to end only if the user is able to make an appointment.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for a Google Assistant Action, or for one of the other integrations in Dialogflow?

Comment: It is for a Google Assistant Action.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you're using and the contents of your `package.json`? `agent.end()` works for some libraries, but not others, and seeing your code will help us help you.